# What's the meaning of this sentence? (I'm confused by the sentence after the comma)

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, phrases

What's the meaning of this sentence ? (I'm confused by the sentence after the comma)

> To conquer fear is the beginning of wisdom, in the pursuit of truth as
> in the endeavor after a worthy manner of life.

Comment: Can you please provide a little bit more context? Why you are confused by the sentence after the comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is saying that:

"To conquer fear is the beginning of wisdom" is true, both when trying to find truth in general, and when trying to live life in a good way. That is, it says that this rule applies both to "the pursuit of truth" and to "the endeavor after a worthy manner of life."

The use of "the endeavor after" seems a bit awkward to me, although grammatically perfectly correct. It means "the attempt to achieve" or perhaps "striving to achieve" expresses it a bit better, as "endeavor" implies continued effort.